# Calling two functions in a C code stops the program

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

i'm developing a MongoDB interpreter and during my work on that i wrote some function to extract some strings from a char array.
The first function gets a string between two separators.

```
char* getContent(char* doc,char firstsep,char secsep){
int whichsep = 0, i = 0 , j = 0;
char* d;
d = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));

while(whichsep != 2){
    if(whichsep == 1) {
        d[j]=doc[i];
        j++;
    }
    if(doc[i]==firstsep) whichsep = 1;
    if(doc[i]==secsep) whichsep = 2;
    i++;
}
d[j-1]='\0';
return d;
};
```

The second function checks if a string contains "_id"

```
    int containsID(char* doc){

int i=0,j=0,c=0;
int * colonpos = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
while(doc[i]!= '\0') {
    if(doc[i]==':' ){
        colonpos[j]=i;
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
colonpos[j] = 0;
char*  id = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
int containsID = 0;
i=0;j=0;
while( colonpos[i] != 0 && containsID !=1 ){

    j=colonpos[i]-1;
    while(doc[j]!=','&& doc[j]!='{'){
        id[c]=doc[j];
        j--;
        c++;
    }
    id[c]='\0';
    id = flipArray(id);
    if(strcmp(id,"_id")==0)
    containsID = 1 ;
    c=0;
    i++;
}
return containsID ;

};
```

and here is the main function

```
int main()
{
char* doc = "db.__fdlkdf.insert({p:231,g:{a:21},tomato:[21,25]})";
if(containsID(doc)==0) puts("no  id ");
else puts("has id");

char* e1 = (char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
strcpy(e1,getContent(doc,'(',')'));
printf("%s\n",e1);


return 0 ;
}
```

when i run the file it shows this :

[image]

but when I call the functions separately the program works!

I'd be gladly thankful if you guys could help me out !

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through your code with the debugger?

Comment: `d = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));` is allocating single `char`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I am not sure stepping will help here..

Comment: I tried calling other functions and they seem to work fine together but when i call getContent it stops working .. i guess it's some pointer problem but i can't find it. The program also stops when i try to a function inside another one.

Comment: @EugeneSh. even if it allocates one single char it points on the others. u can try to call one function only and it's working.

Comment: Do you know what allocation is for? To tell to OS - *I want this memory*. Otherwise you are touching something that is not yours and getting punished.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I didn't get your question .. but I tried the code on kali linux it worked fine but on windows it keeps stopping

Comment: Plain and simple: Accessing a memory which was not allocated is causing an **undefined behavior** (i.e. sometimes it is crashing. Sometimes it is not. Sometimes it might even do some more nasty stuff).

Comment: i reallocated my arrays correctly, it worked thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You program invokes undefined behavior. Do not expect anything good.
In statement

```
d[j]=doc[i];
```

for `i > 0`, you are accessing array out of bound. `d` is an array of 1 `char` only and similarly `colonpos` and `id` in second function.

Comment: it worked thank you :D

Comment: @ELMesaoudiZakariae, you have to accept his Answer. not just smile to him :)

Answer (score 0):

this is a working code,

```
char* getContent(char* doc,char firstsep,char secsep){
  int len;
  char *doc2, *buff;
  // try to find first delimiter
  while( *doc != firstsep){
    if(!*doc)
      return NULL;
    doc++;
  }

  doc++; // firstsep found skip in one char next

  doc2=doc;

  // try to find second  delimiter
  while(*doc2 != secsep){
    if(! doc2)
      return NULL;
        doc2++;
  }

  // its all OK, copy it;
  len = doc2 - doc;
  buff=malloc(len *sizeof(char));

  if(buff){
    memcpy(buff,doc,len);
    buff[len]=0;
  }

  return buff;

};
```